# Reload images after click

Tags: java, android

I need help, I have tables 3x3. How to make reload image in gridView after click? I want make simple application 1 good click = 1 point.

```
public void losowanieTablicy() {
int[] str_names = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
shuffle(str_names);
shuffle(imgIds);

for (int i = 0; i < imgIds.length; i++) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(imgIds[i]);
    final String str = "img_" + str_names[i]; // zakladajac ze str_names.length == imgIds.length
    img.setImageDrawable(
        getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "mipmap", getApplicationContext()))
    );
    }
}

public void shuffle(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // between i and n-1
        int r = i + (int)(Math.random() * (n - i));
        int tmp = a[i]; // swap
        a[i] = a[r];
        a[r] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use an onClickListener for your ImageView and then define a function that cycles through an array of images

Comment: Can you give me any example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an OnClick like this:

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(imgIds[i]);
img.setClickable(true); 
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   img.setImageDrawable(
    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "mipmap", getApplicationContext()))
);
}
});
```